# Xamarin Forms - how to display/Bind List in ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a cart where i store all of my orders , How to display List in ListView?

i tried doing these codes

**CustomerOrder.cs**

```
public class CustomerOrder
    {
        public string menuname { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string qty { get; set; }
        public string mcode { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustList
    {
        //i want to display/bind this in Listview
        public List<CustomerOrder> CUSTOMER_ORDER { get; set; }
    }
```

**OrderCart.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyCart" ItemSelected="MyCart_ItemSelected"  ItemsSource="{Binding CUSTOMER_ORDER}" RowHeight="50">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid>

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding menuname}" Font="30" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding qty}" Font="30" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding price}" Font="30" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding mcode}" Font="30" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Comment: I don’t see a two dimensional array in your sample. Is there code missing?

Comment: @SwapnilShah i editted it i meant List not array thank you! for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might missing PropertyChanged event.

```
public class CustList:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //i want to display/bind this in Listview
        private List<CustomerOrder> _CUSTOMER_ORDER
        public List<CustomerOrder> CUSTOMER_ORDER 
        { 
          get{return _CUSTOMER_ORDER;}
          set{
              _CUSTOMER_ORDER=value;
              OnPropertyChanged("CUSTOMER_ORDER");
             } 
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, 
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And one more thing is you have to apply bindingcontext for your xaml if you are missing that.

Answer (score 1):

If MyCart is any instance of CustList,

In your bindings, you can {Binding CUSTOMER_ORDER.menuname}.

You have to give it path to the data.

Comment: how do you give path?

Comment: ` <ListView x:Name="MyCart" ItemsSource="{Binding CustList}" >`

Comment: just like this?