# Xamarin.Forms how to Bind background color depending on conditions

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

how can you bind background color depending on status
i tried this code and it didn't work

```
var cat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableStat>>(response);
                for(int i = 0;i<cat.Count;i++)
                {
                    if (cat[i].table_status == "Available")
                    {
                        color = "Green";
                        this.BindingContext = color;
                    }
                    else if (cat[i].table_status == "Unavailable")
                    {
                        color = "Black";
                        this.BindingContext = color;
                    }

                }
```

and i binded the color to the .xaml

```
 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  BackgroundColor="{Binding color}">
```

Comment: are you using mvvm?

Comment: yes , i'm using restapi to gather the data @Arvindraja

Comment: You need to create a converter to set the color depend on condition, you can follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325971/how-to-change-bg-color-for-listview-viewcell-contextactions/52328402#52328402)

Comment: And where are the solution?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you can only bind to public properties

```
public Color BGColor { get; set; }

BindingContext = this;
```

then in your code, set that Property's value - you may also need to implement INPC on your class

```
            for(int i = 0;i<cat.Count;i++)
            {
                if (cat[i].table_status == "Available")
                {
                    BGColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (cat[i].table_status == "Unavailable")
                {
                    BGColor = Color.Black;
                }

            }
```

Comment: where should input the `BindingContext = this`  below the ` InitializeComponent();` ?

Comment: ` BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}"` then i will Bind the BGColor like this?

Comment: did you also implement INPC on your class?  Alternatively, you could just explicitly set the BackgroundColor property instead of using Bindings

Comment: what's INPC? how do i implement it?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged - this has been explained to you in previous questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231810/xamarin-forms-how-to-display-bind-list-in-listview

Comment: oh ok thanks i'm just not familliar to the term INPC thanks! it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing this.BindingContext without an observer being called on. So the color changes, but the View does not get notified.

Add a 'set' to the color containing a RaisePropertyChanged, like below:

```
 set { color = value; 
         RaisePropertyChanged("Model");  //<- this should tell the view to update
     }
```

Now anytime color is being changed a trigger is being made to the View to update the state of the bound color.